# How to make multiple page application in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to open a new page when i click a login button. But the problem is when i use 
`dojo.byId("someid").innerHTML="response page from spring controller"`

Dojo Java script codes are not loaded in the new page.But if i use some declarative DOJO code it works like :

```
 <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">Click Me!
                        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
 alert("hello");
```

What should i do?? A sample example with multiple dojo page will be good to understand

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using spring web for your app, so I guess you are using some templating/views technology with it...

You should put your dojo initialization code inside a template that will be shared accross all your views.

More on this here : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html

Alternatively, if you're using jsp, you can put the dojo code in a separate jsp file, and include it in all your pages through : 
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/dojo_header.jsp" %>